# Kronecker product parameters

Tags: matlab, parameters, kronecker-product

Between what variables is this `kron` function doing the Kronecker product? (MATLAB)

```matlab
y = kron(x,[1:size(x)]);
```

I understand what the first variable is, but what does `[1:size(x)]` mean? Don't you need to put an array/list before it so it means something?

Comment: The great thing about interactive languages like MATLAB is that you can just run a portion of code and see what it does. You can actually type `1:size(x)` at the command prompt and see exactly what it means.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`[1:size(x)]`  will produce a vector the size of vector x, and his entries will be:
`[1,2,3,...,n]`

Answer (score 3):

If `x` is a column vector, then `n=size(x)` will be its length and `1:size(x)` will be the row vector `[1...n]`.

If x is a matrix or higher dimensions, the expression `1:size(x)` will take the row count only.

IF the Kronecker Product between those quantities makes sense or not, it depends on your application.